# How to get object from previous view(CBV) in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I tried to get the object value in CreateView from previous DetailView. But Failed. Is there any simple way to do this?

In this code, how can I replace this '???'(*in **CreateView***) by an album object where **album.pk == id** according to 'item-add'(`url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/pic/add/$', views.ItemCreate.as_view(), name='item-add')`)

models.py

```
class Album(models.Model):
    credit = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.FileField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('picture:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.credit


class Item(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('upload_date', 'caption')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('picture:item-detail', kwargs={ 'id': self.album_id , 'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

views.py

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'picture/detail.html'

class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = Item
    fields = ['album', 'file_type', 'caption']

    def get_initial(self):
        album = ???
        return {
            'album': album,
            'file_type': 't',
        }
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
# /picture/<album_id>/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
# /picture/<album_id>/<pic_id>
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item-detail'),
# /picture/<album_id>/pic/add
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/pic/add/$', views.ItemCreate.as_view(), name='item-add'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key is passed as an `id` URL parameter, so you can access this with `self.kwargs`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = Item
    fields = ['album', 'file_type', 'caption']

    def get_initial(self):
        album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=self.kwargs['id'])
        return {
            'album': album,
            'file_type': 't',
        }
```